# What is the term used for adding an 's onto a name?

Tags: possessives, spelling, terminology, names

I realise the title doesn't make much sense, it's a hard one to ask, so I will describe the situation...

The other day my ex's mother was sending me texts and said "it's always Dannies world". Of course when referring to a person, you don't add *ies* onto the name, it would be *Danny's*.

I wanted to reply explaining that isn't how it's done whilst feeling smug, but couldn't think of the term used for that. I know it's not plural, so I couldn't say "the plural of *Danny* isn't *Dannies*".

What could I have said?

Answer (score 4):

It's called *possessive 's*, sometimes *genitive 's*, sometimes [the Saxon genitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_possessive), sometimes the [genitive case ending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitive_case#English).

Comment: thank you very much, so would the sentence be " the possessive of Danny isn't Dannies"?

Comment: @dannyjohnson - You're welcome! Yes, I guess so!

Comment: @dannyjohnson Of course, you will sound smug if you mention it. But perhaps that doesn't matter!

Comment: @Araucaria i would! the time has passed now anyway, just wanted to know as it was bugging me.